# Login-in by roles feathers-authentication

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

i have two users in database and they have the same email and password, but different roles. It look like:

```
  email        pass   roles
+------------+------+-------
 1@gmail.com   123    user
 1@gmail.com   123    admin
```

and when user try to login in, i send request with params

```
{
    email:"1@1.ru"
    password:"123"
    roles:"user"
    strategy:"local"
}
```

The questuin is:how i can to identify user by role (when i send from front-end req with param roles:"user" user must to login by role "user", when roles:"admin" - by admin)

It's my hook from auth

```
app.service('authentication').hooks({
before: {
  create: [
    authentication.hooks.authenticate(['local', 'jwt'])
  ],
  remove: [
    authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 2):

A user (or other authenticated) entity should be uniquely identifiable so it makes more sense to store a list of roles for one user like this:

```
  email        pass   roles
+------------+------+-------
 1@gmail.com   123    user,admin
```

And then can log in with that user and in a hook check if the roles list contains what you need:

```
const { Forbidden } = require('feathers-errors');

function hasRole(name) {
  return function(context) {
    const { user = {} } = context.params;

    if(!user.roles || !user.roles.split(',').includes(name)) {
      throw new Forbidden('You are not allowed to access this');
    }
  }
}

app.service('myservice').hooks({
  before: {
    get: [ hasRole('user') ],
    find: [ hasRole('user') ],
    create: [ hasRole('admin') ],
    patch: [ hasRole('admin') ],
    update: [ hasRole('admin') ],
    remove: [ hasRole('admin') ]
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem is password in role 'admin' may differ in role 'user'

Comment: You might be able to solve this with a custom verifier (https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#verifier) by looking at the request object. I wouldn't recommend having two different accounts associated with the same username however.